# Why does Laravel send blank emails?

Tags: php, email, laravel

I have the following code:

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message) use ($user){
        $message->from('xxx@xxx.xxx', 'XXXXX');
        $message->to($user['email'], $user['name'])->subject('Welcome to My Laravel app!');
    });
```

Now, it doesn't matter what I put in the email template (emails.welcome) the email message is always blank!

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Have you looked into your logs, nginx log, laravel log?

Comment: What does the template look like? And what does data look like?

Comment: The log doesn't show anything wrong, and the template is fine. Even if I place plane text in the template, the email still comes blank.

Answer (score 0):

go to app/config/mail.php

in line 57

```
'from' => array('address' => null, 'name' => null),
```

set the value for the address and name